# Join JPA entities with complex association table without creating the association entity?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am trying to do a ManyToMany join between two JPA entities using an association table that is not very straightforward. I want to know if there is a way to achieve this without creating an entity of the association table (similar to using @JoinTable).

### Database Schema

**TableA**
- ID (PK)
- Name

**TableB**
- ID (PK)
- Name

**TableMapping**
- ID (PK)
- Parent_ID (FK) --> TableMapping.ID
- A_ID (FK) --> TableA.ID
- B_ID (FK) --> TableB.ID

### Example

```
TableA  
ID     Name 
-----------------------  
A1     Algebra  
A2     Data Structures  
A3     Economics  

TableB  
ID     Name  
------------------------  
B1     Beginner  
B2     Advanced  

TableMapping  
ID     Parent_ID    A_ID     B_ID  
----------------------------------  
1        NULL       NULL       B1  
2        NULL       NULL       B2 
3         1          A1       NULL  
4         2          A2       NULL  
5         2          A3       NULL
```

The mapping is stored the way I described above for reasons I do not know and I cannot change that. It is being used like this in a ton of places and I have to work with the way it is. Essentially, the data in TableMapping can be simplified to something like this.

```
A_ID    B_ID  
-------------  
 A1      B1
 A2      B2
 A3      B2
```

From my understanding of the problems, there are two ways of doing this:

1. Create an entity of the association table and map the two entities with the association table entity. This should work, but it would be great if I can do something like @JoinTable and not have to create an entity for this association table since all it does is map entities in TableA to entities in TableB.
2. Create a view which simplifies the association between the two tables into a single database row for each mapping as shown above. Use the view in @JoinTable.

Note: To keep the code simple, I have not created any getter / setters or constructors.

### Entity Code

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableA")
public class EntityA {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    public String name;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TableB")
public class EntityB {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    public String name;

    // Want to add below mapping
    // @ManyToMany
    // @JoinTable or equivalent?? 
    // public Set<EntityA> aEntitySet;
}
```

I don't know if there is a way to join two entities using this weird mapping table without creating an entity or view. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You should first learn Database Normalization. You should choose OneToMany instead of ManyToMany. `Tip:` you can do this by adding another table between the two tables.

Also, the objects you create to use OneToMany must be List or Set.
[you can look here for OneToMany Annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many)

Comment: I do have a mapping table between the two entities (TableMapping in my example).  This is an existing DB design and I have to work with the way it is. Since I only want to read from this DB, I am looking for a way to not have to create entity for the association table. I have another case where two entities are joined by a mapping table but it is much simpler and I was able to map the two entities with the help of @JoinTable without creating the mapping table entity. Again, only reading from those 2 entities, not worried about writes.

Comment: I have the same need. This is one of the reasosn I f**** hate JPA and hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is if it's possible to avoid creating some sort of association entity, I believe the answer would be no. It needs a place to be persisted after all.

Comment: Makes sense. The only reason I was trying to find a way to avoid persisting the association is because I will never be writing anything to the DB, just reading from it. All the entities would be read only.